# Pushing Hash onto Array: last Hash overwriting previous array elements

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, hash

I have the following Ruby script:

```
arr = ['bob', 'jack', 'smith']
array_of_hashes = Array.new
hash = Hash.new

arr.each do |item|
  hash.clear
  hash[:name] = item
  array_of_hashes << hash
end

puts array_of_hashes
```

This returns an array of hashes, whose :name keys are all from the last element.

```
[
    [0] {
        :name => "smith"
    },
    [1] {
        :name => "smith"
    },
    [2] {
        :name => "smith"
    }
]
```

I would expect it to return the following, but I'm stuck trying to figure out why the last Hash element is overwriting all previous array elements:

```
[
    [0] {
        :name => "bob"
    },
    [1] {
        :name => "jack"
    },
    [2] {
        :name => "smith"
    }
]
```

EDIT: Thank you all for your answers. It's nice to have some different methods laid out of accomplishing the same thing. I've tested each solution and each one is great. I ended up using the one which was most similar to my original code; but my use case is a simple, local script - it's not being used in an industrial-sized app - in which case, I would probably choose a different solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try something like

```
arr = ['bob', 'jack', 'smith']
array_of_hashes = Array.new

arr.each { |item|
  hash = Hash.new
  hash[:name] = item
  array_of_hashes << hash
}

puts array_of_hashes
```

with a new instance being pushed into the array for every new item.

Comment: Thanks for your post Ed; I really like how this code clearly illustrates the flaw in my original code - that is, I only had one hash I was dealing with and this code creates a new hash each array item.

Comment: I'm glad it helped, @singularity. Thanks for the upvote.

Comment: I've accepted this answer now because it's what I ended up doing. It was the quickest way from my original code to a working script. Essentially, `Hash.new` had to be within the `arr.each` block. `.clear` is not needed as well. Although it might not be the most elegant solution, it's the most practical for my scenario and gets the job done.

Answer (score 5):

Look at your code carefully, you'll see that you've only created a single instance of `Hash`.  Your iterator keeps blowing away earlier efforts with `.clear`, setting the element to the current iterate, and adding the reference to that one `Hash` object to different array locations in `array_of_hashes`.  But at the end of the day, they all point to the same `Hash` object, and that `Hash` object contains only the last thing you put into it.

Answer (score 4):

Take note of (and understand) the answer by @pjs and the comment by @tadman as they explain why you are getting the results you are getting.

I would actually instead do something like:

```
names = ['bob', 'jack', 'smith']

# combine the results into an array of Hashes
array_of_hashes =
  names.collect do |item|
    { name: item }
  end

# output the results
array_of_hashes # [{name: "bob"}, {name: "jack"},{name:"smith"}]
```

Some notes:

- The `Array#collect` method will return an array, so you don't need to manually add to an array you've initialized your self.
- You can just return a new Hash for each item which will be returned in the `collect` block

Comment: The key here is that `array << hash` pushes an *object reference* to `hash` into the array and not a copy.

Comment: This seems like the most "rubyish" way of going about this.

Comment: Test the code without the "puts" and see... it shows NO results, sorry. That's why I edited your answer. Try it then edit it yourself.

Comment: @Ed, I've testing it in both irb and pry.  The code works fine.  If you wrap the whole thing within a `def` it will also work.

Comment: I saved it to a file named arrhash2.rb (arrhash.rb was my solution below) and run with "ruby arrhash2.rb". I see NO OUTPUT without the "puts", sorry. It works fine, but displays nothing. At least to me. Not without the "puts".

Comment: Yes, running the code within a ruby file you will need to do something like `puts` to output the value to the user.  Something like `puts array_of_hashes.inspect` would be be closer to what my intent was with showing what the actual value of `array_of_hashes` is.

Answer (score 2):

I would write

```
[:name].product(arr).map { |pair| Hash[[pair]] }
  #=> [{:name=>"bob"}, {:name=>"jack"}, {:name=>"smith"}]
```

or (for Ruby v2.0+)

```
[:name].product(arr).map { |pair| [pair].to_h }
```

The steps:

```
a = [:name].product(arr)
  #=> [[:name, "bob"], [:name, "jack"], [:name, "smith"]]   
enum = a.map
  # => #<Enumerator: [[:name, "bob"], [:name, "jack"], [:name, "smith"]]:map>
```

Note that by sending the method [Enumerator#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-each) to `enum` we obtain the desired result:

```
enum.each { |pair| [pair].to_h }
  #=> [{:name=>"bob"}, {:name=>"jack"}, {:name=>"smith"}]
```

(`Enumerator#each` will invoke [Array#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each) because `a.class #=> Array`.)

`Enumerator#each` sets the block variable to the first element of `enum`:

```
pair = enum.next
  #=> [:name, "bob"]
```

and the block calculation is performed:

```
[pair].to_h
  #=> [[:name, "bob"]].to_h
  #=> {:name=>"bob"}
```

Next, the second element of `enum`, `[:name, "jack"]`, is mapped to:

```
pair = enum.next
  #=> [:name, "jack"] 
[pair].to_h
  #=> [[:name, "jack"]].to_h
  #=> {:name=>"jack"}
```

Lastly,

```
pair = enum.next
  #=> [:name, "smith"] 
[pair].to_h
  #=> [[:name, "smith"]].to_h
  #=> {:name=>"smith"}
```

Comment: This seems elegant. It's a bit over my head, but for the n00bs (myself included), to see the output you can `puts` this or assign it to a var - `hash = [:name].product(arr).map { |pair| [pair].to_h }`

Comment: I will elaborate in the morning. It's less complex than it may initially seem.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the elaboration! That helps demystify the steps quite a bit

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too

```
>>> names = ['bob', 'jack', 'smith']
>>> names.inject([]){|s,p| s << {name: p}}
=> [{:name=>"bob"}, {:name=>"jack"}, {:name=>"smith"}]
```